# Magento 2: Switch the price for 'Sold' label after product is out of stock

Tags: magento, magento2, price

I'm trying to to switch the price for a 'Sold' label on the product page of products that are out of stock.
If a product is sold out, the price should be hidden and in its stead should be a 'Sold' label.

I figured out that the price is placed in catalog_product_view.xml and it calls upon the `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml` file, but I could not figure out where and how to bring in a condition to check whether product is sold out or not.

Can someone help here?
Thanks in advance.

Yuan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you have two parts to this issue

1) Hide price on Product-detail page if product is Out-of-stock

- Prices are defined in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
- called at class: Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render and method: _toHtml()
- You can override the method using DI to below

  ```
      protected function _toHtml()
      {
          /** @var PricingRender $priceRender */
          $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($this->getPriceRender());
          if ($priceRender instanceof PricingRender) {
              $product = $this->getProduct();
              if ($product instanceof SaleableInterface && $product->isAvailable()) {
                  $arguments = $this->getData();
                  $arguments['render_block'] = $this;
                  return $priceRender->render($this->getPriceTypeCode(), $product, $arguments);
              }
          }
          return parent::_toHtml();
      }
  ```
- $product->isAvailable() is the new condition that we have added

2) Show Sold label

- outofstock label is shown by default, but if you still want to show create your block & template in vendor/magento/modul-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

  - and $product->isAvailable() function to check product's availability

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Hiding price for out of stock products in Magento 1.**

RWD Theme

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

**Change**

```
<div class="price-info">
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
</div>
```

**To:**

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="price-info">
        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Default Theme:**

```
\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\default.phtml
```

**Change**

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

**To:**

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**OR**

**Hiding price for out of stock products in Magento 2.**

On admin page, Click on **Stores**, then under the **Setting** section, choose **Configuration**.

In this page, you find the **Inventory** section under **Catalog**. Expand the Stock Options section and you can start to set the custom status of the product.

[image]

Before coming to the Out of stock product section, you need to enter this field.

**Set Items’ Status to be in Stock When Order in Canceled**: **You** choose YES when you want to return items to your stock if an order is canceled.

**Decrease Stock When Order is Placed**: if you want to adjust the quantity on hand when the order is placed, you choose **Yes**

Then we can come to the part that allows you to display or disable the product out of stock in Magento 2.

**You want to display the product out of stock**, you set the Display Out of Stock Products section is **Yes**. In contrast, set **No** if you want to disable it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but your solution is for Magento 2? Maybe I just not getting it, but it looks like it's for Magento 1.

Comment: @whiterabbit please check my answer again I have updated it with Magento 2 also.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the help. Really appreciate it, but I don't want to hide the whole product after being sold out. The product should still be visible, but on the product page the price should be replaced with a 'Sold' label.